# Shiny Layout FluidRow and Columns

Tags: r, layout, shiny

**Layout-Question:** Attached the following figure. I try to adjust the layout in the following way such that I achieve the "red" extensions. Any suggestions how to do that?

[image]

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    mainPanel(width = 12,

              fluidRow(
                  column(6, offset = 0, uiOutput("f1")),
                  column(6, offset = 0, uiOutput("f2"))
              ),
              fluidRow(
                  column(4, offset = 0, uiOutput("f3")),
                  column(4, offset = 0, uiOutput("f4")),
                  column(4, offset = 0, uiOutput("f5"))
              )
)
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$f1 <- renderUI({
        selectizeInput(inputId = "select_visualize_aggregation",
                       label = "F1",
                       choices = c("day", "week"),
                       selected = "week",
                       multiple = FALSE
        )
    })


    ...
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `width = "100%"` in `selectizeInput`:

```
  output$f1 <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput(inputId = "select_visualize_aggregation",
                   label = "F1",
                   choices = c("day", "week"),
                   selected = "week",
                   multiple = FALSE,
                   width = "100%"
    )
  })
```